# Scala @ Functions/Language for HTML documentation - for loop, if statement, etc

Tags: html, scala

I am working a List in a view (html page) from a controller in which I am trying to match up "checked" values in a checkbox.

I grab the selected checkbox values (List A) from a model, grab them in a controller, and send to the view.  I also grab the checkbox selections/options/values (List B) from a model.  So, when I display the page, I cycle through List B, then cycle through List A to see if there is a match.  If there is a match, I display the checkbox as checked, if not, I display the checkbox value.

Here is the Scala:

```
@(profileForm: Form[Application.ProfileRegister], servicesList: java.util.List[Service], profile: Profile, servicesSelected: java.util.List[String])

@main(null) {

...

    <label class="title">Services Provided:<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="column column1">
        @for(service <- servicesList) {
            @for(checkService <- servicesSelected) {
                @if(checkService.equals(service.name)) {
                    <label><input type="checkbox" checked class="selectServices" name="selectServices" id="selectServices" value=@service.name><span>@service.name</span></label>
                } else {
                    <label><input type="checkbox" class="selectServices" name="selectServices" id="selectServices" value=@service.name><span>@service.name</span></label>
                }                       
            }
        }
    </div>

...

}
```

This is duplicating the values in the checkbox, but it also works with the checked values.  This is displayed here:

[image]

Is this correct Scala?

And my other question is - where do they have documentation on the Scala @ language that can be used within views (html)?  I have searched but cannot locate what I am looking for.  Can I use variables within these statements or just HTML?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaner, no need for the extra iteration that is producing the duplicates:

```
 @for(service <- servicesList) {
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" @if(servicesSelected contains service.name) {checked} class="selectServices" name="selectServices" id="selectServices" value=@service.name>
      <span>@service.name</span>
    </label>                    
 }
```

The templating language is called "twirl" and is documented here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates